# GetTransactionDetails and permissions in the new REST API world

Tags: paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I'm still trying to wrap my head around all this, so my apologies if I've made a mistake, but it seems like the old NVP apps that are now unable to be registered as of December 1st had some features available that can't be replicated in the new REST world order...

Here's what I want/need:  I need to be able to translate buyer-side transaction IDs into my seller-side transaction IDs, and I want to be able to do this on a webserver that is secure but I don't want it to have full access to my account, so I'd like fine-grained authz for this server.

It seems like I am a couple days too late to actually get what I want/need.  Basically, [GetTransactionDetails](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/GetTransactionDetails_API_Operation_NVP/) does exactly what I want (convert buyer to seller transaction IDs, and returns the rest of the transaction information for good measure). And, although I haven't gotten it working, it looks like the Permissions SDK plus an NVP AppID would allow me to have just the [TRANSACTION_DETAILS permission](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/permissions-service/integration-guide/PermissionsAbout/?mark=permissions-%C2%ADservice%20integration-%C2%ADguide%20PermissionsAbout#permission-groups) on this service which is exactly what I want.

However, as of Friday apparently I can't get an AppID for the classic NVP API?  If so, my timing is impeccable.

Trying to figure out how to do this in the REST API has proven difficult.  [This thread](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/issues/854) talks about the sale record, which does indeed take a buyer-side transaction ID, but it does not actually translate it into a seller-side one.  It does have the custom field, which helps me a little, but I really need the seller-side transaction ID.  It looks like maybe the parent_payment URL in the return from the sale might help, but the API started returning PERMISSION_DENIED on me even on previously successful queries so I can't exactly test this right now.  And, even if that did work, it seems like the permissions on the REST API are incredibly coarse compared to the Permissions SDK, for example the sale endpoint is under /v1/payments which seems to also include refunds and all kinds of other stuff I don't want exposed.  It looks like there's a Transaction Search permission but it's marked beta and it didn't work for querying a sale for me.  But maybe it means they're working on it?

What are my options here?

Thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I played around with this for a while, and it seems like the PayPal REST API is just not very good.  So, I worked around the limitations here using AWS Lambda and its fine-grained IAM permissions.  I created a Lambda function that took my PayPal NVP credentials as encrypted env vars, and an IAM account that could only call my Lambda function, and so now I've got a microservice that will translate transaction IDs and return some extra info (custom and email) from the transaction to boot.

I wish I didn't have to use AWS to work around PayPal's limitations (which seem to be getting worse with the REST API, the NVP api would have been fine if I could have gotten and AppID and used the Permissions SDK), but oh well.

Chris